# Loading a project with decorations into QGIS 3.22.10 using PyQGIS code in startup.py file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-customization

Following the instructions given on this page of the QGIS manual:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadproject.html#

I added that code to the `startup.py` file, which I use to customise QGIS, with the result that the project is loaded but the decorations (title, copyright, scale) are not displayed.
Unfortunately, I cannot use the `-project (projectfile)` option from the QGIS command line because I have already reached the 260-character file path length limit in Windows .LNK files.

Code from my file startup.py:

```
from qgis.utils import iface    
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
data_dir = os.path.join('D:', 'MyProject_GPKG')
project = QgsProject.instance()
project_name = 'MyProject.qgs'
project_path = os.path.join(data_dir, project_name)
project.read(project_path)
```

Path in Windows .LNK file:

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.10\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe" --customizationfile "D:\MyProject_GPKG\QGIS3.ini" --code "D:\MyProject_GPKG\startup.py"
```

Comment: Without your `startup.py` code or any kind of reproducible code sample, how exactly are you expecting anyone to be able to help you ? There is most likely "something" (which we can't determine without the actual code) wrong with it.

Comment: Even with the code copied from the manual, the decorations are not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `iface.addProject(project_path)` instead of `QgsProject.instance().read(project_path)`

I am not certain of why but the former works fine while the latter fails even though the default flags suggests it should also work

Comment: Thank you Louis for the quick reply, your solution works perfectly.
Sorry for the initial incompleteness of the question but sometimes I forget that you developers don't have a crystal ball :-)

Comment: No problem, having the most detailed question possible insures you get clearer, quicker and more precise answers. (btw remember to accept answers if they are satisfactory)